# animation pattern not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am trying the animation pattern.All paterns except the last six are working properly. I want the last six pattern to happen together after all other patternshave happened.But using this code it oscillates in a different manner. The last6 pattern doesn't happen together. Plz help me 
My code is

```
$j(document).ready(function () {
$j("#circle").show().animate({
    top: '260px'
}, 1000, function () {
    $j("#v_logo").animate({
        opacity: '1'
    }, 400, function () {
        $j("#v_logo").animate({
            height: '150px',
            width: '100px',
            top: '260px',
            left: '450px'
        }, 2000, function () {
            $j("#s_logo").animate({
                opacity: '1'
            }, 400, function () {
                $j("#s_logo").animate({
                    height: '150px',
                    width: '100px',
                    top: '260px',
                    left: '450px'
                }, 2000, function () {
                    $j("#circle,#v_logo,#s_logo").animate({
                        height: '300px',
                        width: '200px',
                        top: '180px',
                        left: '380px'
                    }, 2000, function () {
                        $j("#circle,#v_logo,#s_logo").animate({
                            height: '100px',
                            width: '66px',
                            top: '110px',
                            left: '20px'
                        }, 1500, function () {
                            $j("#v").animate({
                                height: '120px',
                                width: '120px',
                                top: '300px',
                                left: '130px',
                                opacity: '1'
                            }, 500, function () {
                                $j("#s").animate({
                                    height: '100px',
                                    width: '100px',
                                    top: '260px',
                                    left: '260px',
                                    opacity: '1'
                                }, 500, function () {
                                    $j("#t").animate({
                                        height: '120px',
                                        width: '120px',
                                        top: '300px',
                                        left: '350px',
                                        opacity: '1'
                                    }, 500, function () {
                                        $j("#u").animate({
                                            height: '120px',
                                            width: '120px',
                                            top: '260px',
                                            left: '460px',
                                            opacity: '1'
                                        }, 500, function () {
                                            $j("#d").animate({
                                                height: '120px',
                                                width: '120px',
                                                top: '300px',
                                                left: '600px',
                                                opacity: '1'
                                            }, 500, function () {
                                                $j("#y").animate({
                                                    height: '120px',
                                                    width: '120px',
                                                    top: '260px',
                                                    left: '710px',
                                                    opacity: '1'
                                                }, 500, function () {
                                                    $j("#v").animate({
                                                        height: '120px',
                                                        width: '120px',
                                                        top: '280px',
                                                        left: '130px',
                                                        opacity: '1'
                                                    });
                                                    $j("#s").animate({
                                                        height: '100px',
                                                        width: '100px',
                                                        top: '280px',
                                                        left: '260px',
                                                        opacity: '1'
                                                    });
                                                    $j("#t").animate({
                                                        height: '120px',
                                                        width: '120px',
                                                        top: '280px',
                                                        left: '350px',
                                                        opacity: '1'
                                                    });
                                                    $j("#u").animate({
                                                        height: '120px',
                                                        width: '120px',
                                                        top: '280px',
                                                        left: '460px',
                                                        opacity: '1'
                                                    });
                                                    $j("#d").animate({
                                                        height: '120px',
                                                        width: '120px',
                                                        top: '280px',
                                                        left: '600px',
                                                        opacity: '1'
                                                    });
                                                    $j("#y").animate({
                                                        height: '120px',
                                                        width: '120px',
                                                        top: '280px',
                                                        left: '710px',
                                                        opacity: '1'
                                                    });
                                                });
                                            });
                                        });
                                    });
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
});
```

my html code is

```
<img src="circle.gif" id="circle"style="position:absolute;top:100px;left:450px;display:none;height:150px;width:100px" />
<img src="v_logo.gif" id="v_logo"style="position:absolute;top:340px;left:495px;opacity:0;height:2px;width:2px" />
<img src="s_logo.gif" id="s_logo"style="position:absolute;top:340px;left:520px;opacity:0;height:2px;width:2px" />
<img src="v.gif" id="v"style="position:absolute;top:300px;left:20px;height:120px;width:120px;opacity:0" />
<img src="s.gif" id="s"style="position:absolute;top:100px;left:260px;height:100px;width:100px;opacity:0" />
<img src="t.gif" id="t"style="position:absolute;top:550px;left:350px;height:120px;width:120px;opacity:0" />
<img src="u.gif" id="u"style="position:absolute;top:100px;left:460px;height:120px;width:120px;opacity:0" />
<img src="d.gif" id="d"style="position:absolute;top:550px;left:600px;height:120px;width:120px;opacity:0" />
<img src="y.gif" id="y"style="position:absolute;top:260px;left:970px;height:120px;width:120px;opacity:0" />
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing the HTML as well? And please add some details about what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @SinghRajputKushagra can you afford another library? I think you would agree that seems pretty difficult to maintain. I am recommending [GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap). [`TimelineMax`](http://greensock.com/timelinemax) to be more specific.

Comment: actually i am using other lib also and moreover most of the time there is a conflict between js files. So i prefered using it simply but not able to get where i am making mistake

Comment: @SinghRajputKushagra I am just saying that the sequencing bits can so easily be managed by the framework I am proposing. Any way, can you update your `img` tags with absolute links so we can actually be able to see the animation in action in order to debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you animate on multiple element `$("#circle,#v_logo,#s_logo")` the callback is fired for each (three times in this case).
You can prevent this from happening by creating a boolean variable. Switch the boolean variable once the first is complete and prevent the rest of the code to be run muktple times.

Also, when animating the same element multiple times, you can let jQuery's queue do the hard work ;)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$j = jQuery;
$j("#circle").show().animate({
    top: '260px'
}, 1000, function () {
    $j("#v_logo").animate({
        opacity: '1'
    }, 400);
    
    $j("#v_logo").animate({
            height: '150px',
            width: '100px',
            top: '260px',
            left: '450px'
        }, 2000, function () {
            $j("#s_logo").animate({
                opacity: '1'
            }, 400);
      
            $j("#s_logo").animate({
                    height: '150px',
                    width: '100px',
                    top: '260px',
                    left: '450px'
                }, 2000, function () {
                    $j("#circle,#v_logo,#s_logo").animate({
                        height: '300px',
                        width: '200px',
                        top: '180px',
                        left: '380px'
                    }, 2000);
                    
                    var firstDone = false;
              
                    $j("#circle,#v_logo,#s_logo").animate({
                            height: '100px',
                            width: '66px',
                            top: '110px',
                            left: '20px'
                        }, 1500, function () {
                            
                            if(!firstDone) {
                              firstDone = true;
                            $j("#v").animate({
                                height: '120px',
                                width: '120px',
                                left: '130px',
                                opacity: '1'
                            }, 500, function () {
                                $j("#s").animate({
                                    top: '260px',
                                    opacity: '1'
                                }, 500, function () {
                                    $j("#t").animate({
                                        top: '300px',
                                        opacity: '1'
                                    }, 500, function () {
                                        $j("#u").animate({
                                            top: '260px',
                                            opacity: '1'
                                        }, 500, function () {
                                            $j("#d").animate({
                                                top: '300px',
                                                opacity: '1'
                                            }, 500, function () {
                                                $j("#y").animate({
                                                    left: '710px',
                                                    opacity: '1'
                                                }, 500, function () {
                                                    $j("#v").animate({
                                                        top: '280px'
                                                    });
                                                    $j("#s").animate({
                                                        top: '280px'
                                                    });
                                                    $j("#t").animate({
                                                        top: '280px'
                                                    });
                                                    $j("#u").animate({
                                                        top: '280px'
                                                    });
                                                    $j("#d").animate({
                                                        top: '280px'
                                                    });
                                                    $j("#y").animate({
                                                        top: '280px'
                                                    });
                                                });
                                            });
                                        });
                                    });
                                });
                            });
                              }
                        });
              
                });
      
        });
    
});
});
```

```css
img { border: 1px solid #00f; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="circle.gif" id="circle"style="position:absolute;top:100px;left:450px;display:none;height:150px;width:100px" />
<img src="v_logo.gif" id="v_logo"style="position:absolute;top:340px;left:495px;opacity:0;height:2px;width:2px" />
<img src="s_logo.gif" id="s_logo"style="position:absolute;top:340px;left:520px;opacity:0;height:2px;width:2px" />
<img src="v.gif" id="v"style="position:absolute;top:300px;left:20px;height:120px;width:120px;opacity:0" />
<img src="s.gif" id="s"style="position:absolute;top:100px;left:260px;height:100px;width:100px;opacity:0" />
<img src="t.gif" id="t"style="position:absolute;top:550px;left:350px;height:120px;width:120px;opacity:0" />
<img src="u.gif" id="u"style="position:absolute;top:100px;left:460px;height:120px;width:120px;opacity:0" />
<img src="d.gif" id="d"style="position:absolute;top:550px;left:600px;height:120px;width:120px;opacity:0" />
<img src="y.gif" id="y"style="position:absolute;top:260px;left:970px;height:120px;width:120px;opacity:0" />
```

Comment: but can u xplain the logic i am not getting it

Comment: What part of the logic are you not getting? How the callback is fired three times or how the jQuert queue works?

Comment: When you de an animate on an element, jQuery will add it to a queue for that element. Only to execute the animation when the previous is done.